# org.apache.jasper.JasperException Exception after adding Axis2 1.6.2 jars in my spring application

Tags: spring

I am getting bellow error after adding axis2 jars, please me help out on this.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Comment: can you show the full stacktrace? Also are you using Maven?

Comment: Hi Unheilig, Thanks for the reply, the above is resolved, that's because of servlet jar in my built war, once i exclude that its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you first analyze the bugs in this version of axis jar. In case you try to create a context using this jar you may dump several .jar files in apache-tocat /temp/ directory and that will fill up all your space on the server.
Just in case it happens, for a temporary fix your must have to restart tomcat or find the right axis2 jar.